# Getting class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to join node to the active cluster error while starting Apache Ignite client

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, ignite

I am trying start Apache ignite with Postgres as persistence.

Apache ignite server is running in my local, apache ignite client I am running from a spring boot application.

Please see the below code for Apache ignite with Postgres as persistence config

```
@Configuration
@EnableIgniteRepositories(value = "com.cache.*")
public class IgniteCacheConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Ignite igniteInstance() {
        return Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration());
    }

    @Bean(name = "igniteConfiguration")
    public IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration() {
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
        igniteConfiguration.setIgniteInstanceName("testIgniteInstance");
        igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(true);
        igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        igniteConfiguration.setLocalHost("127.0.0.1");

        TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
        tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
        tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalPort(47500);
        tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalPortRange(9);
        igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);

        TcpCommunicationSpi communicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
        communicationSpi.setLocalAddress("localhost");
        communicationSpi.setLocalPort(48100);
        communicationSpi.setSlowClientQueueLimit(1000);
        igniteConfiguration.setCommunicationSpi(communicationSpi);
        igniteConfiguration.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfiguration());
        return igniteConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean(name = "cacheConfiguration")
    public CacheConfiguration[] cacheConfiguration() {
        List<CacheConfiguration> cacheConfigurations = new ArrayList<>();
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, Person> ccfg = new CacheConfiguration("PersonCache");
        // Setting SQL schema for the cache.
        ccfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, Person.class);
        ccfg.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
        ccfg.setWriteBehindFlushFrequency(1000);
        ccfg.setExpiryPolicyFactory(TouchedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(Duration.ONE_MINUTE));
        // ccfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC).setBackups(1);
        ccfg.setWriteBehindFlushSize(0);
        ccfg.setWriteBehindFlushThreadCount(1);
        ccfg.setWriteBehindBatchSize(1);
        ccfg.setReadThrough(true);
        ccfg.setWriteThrough(true);

        CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<Integer, Person> factory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<>();
        factory.setDialect(new BasicJdbcDialect());
        factory.setDataSourceFactory((Factory<DataSource>)() -> {

            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
            dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
            dataSource.setPassword("password");
            return dataSource;
        });

        JdbcType personType = new JdbcType();
        personType.setCacheName("PersonCache");
        personType.setKeyType(Integer.class);
        personType.setValueType(Person.class);
        personType.setDatabaseTable("PERSON");

        personType.setKeyFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "id", Integer.class, "id"));

        personType.setValueFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "id", Integer.class, "id"));
        personType.setValueFields(new JdbcTypeField(java.sql.Types.VARCHAR, "first_name", String.class, "firstName"));
        personType.setValueFields(new JdbcTypeField(java.sql.Types.VARCHAR, "last_name", String.class, "lastName"));
        personType.setValueFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "age", Integer.class, "age"));

        factory.setTypes(personType);

        ccfg.setCacheStoreFactory(factory);
        QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity();

        qryEntity.setKeyType(Integer.class.getName());
        qryEntity.setValueType(Person.class.getName());
        qryEntity.setKeyFieldName("id");

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        fields.put("id", "java.lang.Integer");
        fields.put("firstName", "java.lang.String");
        fields.put("lastName", "java.lang.String");
        fields.put("age", "java.lang.Integer");
        qryEntity.setFields(fields);

        ccfg.setQueryEntities(Collections.singletonList(qryEntity));

        cacheConfigurations.add(ccfg);
        return cacheConfigurations.toArray(new CacheConfiguration[cacheConfigurations.size()]);
    }
}
```

}

The POJO class for Person:
public class Person  implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3235823406453902677L;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private int id;
@QuerySqlField
private String firstName;
@QuerySqlField
private String lastName;
@QuerySqlField
private int age;
```

}

I have also created the table in Postgres DB:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSON
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
first_name CHARACTER VARYING(100) NOT NULL,
last_name CHARACTER VARYING(100) NOT NULL,
age INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PERSON_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

When I am trying to start the application I am getting the below error :

**Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to join node to the active cluster (the config of the cache 'PersonCache' has to be merged which is impossible on active grid). Deactivate grid and retry node join or clean the joining node**.
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1997)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1911)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$1.body(ClientImpl.java:302)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:61)

Please let me know what is wrong in the configuration

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you change indexes for a cache while a node is away. Then, when you try to connect it back it doesn't have information about indexes changes. More information in the ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8048. The best way is to follow the hint in exception: join node to the inactive cluster.